# How do I add a KVM guest VM to virsh

Tags: ubuntu, kvm

I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests) to create a KVM guest but I didn't pay attention to this line

> Note: if you want to use Virsh to manage your virtual machines as detailed below, you must add this parameter:1

So the VM is running fine but I'd like to add it to the list of VMs managed with virsh, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another VM (adding `--libvirt qemu:///system` this time), but don't boot it -- `virsh edit` it and replace the path to your virtual disk with your existing VM's disk path.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo virsh define XXX.xml
```

That command can add a vm into virsh persistently.

The command "sudo virsh help"  show help info.

Comment: The XML needs to exist for this command to work which is not the case for the OP.